# What is the idea of "seudas predeh" (Goodbye Party) and where does it come from?

Tags: provenance, meal-seudah

I live in Eretz Yisrael and tonight I was invited to what many chassidim refer to as a "seudas predeh" (or as I somewhat loosely -- or perhaps wrongly "translated" in the title as a "Goodbye Party".)

This often happens here in Israel when a young family move back to America or wherever they might be from.

This person is obviously not leaving the world (chas v'shalom), but leaving what has been his home for years and a kehillah where he has davened.

Where does this minhag come from? What is the point of it? What is the significance?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just a nice way to say goodbye? What makes you think there is any religious significance to it?

Comment: @DoubleAA It definitely is and I'm sure this is isn't the first thing for chassidim to "make up". However I'm trying to find if there is any 'earlier' makor for it. Similar to that of when a Chasson leaves his town to get married in a different town there is a minhag among chassidim to make a seudah. Could also just be an idea of  "תופסים סיבה לעשות מסיבה"

Comment: The Talmud writes (when listing reasons why Tu B'Av is considered an unusually happy day) that one reason was because in the Temple, this was the last day of the year they collected wood. The fact that this was the end of an 'objective' (even if they didn't collect enough wood), was enough to warrant a celebration. I've heard this compared to the end of school/Zman in Yeshiva in that 'completing' a stage in life is in itself a reason for celebration.

Comment: My lack of upvoting is due to your comment "I'm sure this is isn't the first thing for chassidim to "make up"." I resent your contention and feel it is out of line.

Comment: There is also a common "minhag" in yeshivos to have a "סעודת פרידה" when someone leaves the yeshiva. I'm not sure where that comes from, either.

Comment: @GershonGold You're right in a way the quotes and lashon give it the wrong connotation. There are "made up" things that are both good and bad.

Answer (score 3):

A source I have heard for a Seudas Preida is from Elisha. This is mentioned in [Melachim-1 19:21](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14263&st=&pgnum=203) - see Radak that he made a Seuda when he was leaving.

Comment: Where did you "hear" this from?

Comment: @Yehoshua: At a Seudas Preida that was held for me when I left New York